# Insert resultset row in a forEach loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach, ssis, etl

I was wondering if it is possible to insert the row being read by a for each loop in SSIS into another table. As the resultset is being processed by the foreach loop, i want to store the values in the table so they can be referenced again later in my project.

The result set is being stored in a global variable (object).

I'm not sure if this is clear. Please help me think through the problem. Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a DataFlow Task before the foreach Loop and Read the values from the Object variables as Source:

- [Using The SSIS Object Variable As A Data Flow Source](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/)
- [Creating a Source with the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-source-with-the-script-component)